# Error with QMutableListIterator

Tags: qt, qlist, listiterator

After appending an item to a `QList` which is pointed to by a `QMutableListIterator`, I find out the next value of the iterator points outside the list.
Or can't I point the iterator to any where in the list except the beginning or end?
Please I need help.

Answer (score 2):

From the Qt documentation:

> no changes should be done directly to the list while the iterator is active (as opposed to through the iterator), since this could invalidate the iterator and lead to undefined behavior.

Appending to the list might cause it's memory to be reallocated, which would mean that the iterator points to an invalid location.

Comment: Ok. But how do i re-point the iterator to the initial item just before the append action.

Comment: You could keep a count of which item your iterator is currently at, then repeatedly call next() to get back to that point, but honestly, QMutableListIterator seems not to be the right class for what you're trying to do. You would find it easier to just access elements in the list by index.

Comment: OK, I think I now have an idea. Thanks